# Get editing tips on text

Tags: writing

I'd like to work on my writing skills, and would like to get tips and corrections on my articles from time to time. Do you know of a suitable forum to post this stuff?

Comment: Well, is it poems, romance novel, adventure tales, technical documentation, political reports? I would suggest searching for an audience for the content or genre you're writing and asking there for feedback on your style.

Comment: The question seems off-topic for the site since it's not specifically about German. We do have a learning resources FAQ, and perhaps this kind of information should be listed there.